# Window handle mechanism feels tight

Tags: windows, lubrication

I feel like the window mechanism is a bit tight and is starting to rust slowly, is there any lubricant/maintenance that is needed to take care of this?

Thanks!

[image: Window mechanism]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful with window lubricants. If they are greasy/sticky, they will attract dust and dirt (and also get on your clothes).

They make graphite lubricants (generally for locks) that will not leave a greasy residue.   They also make "graphite paint" which is basically paint resin loaded with graphite instead of pigment and filler.

However in a window, the resistance is less likely to be from *pivoting* points and more likely to be from *sliding* points. Graphite paint is a good choice for those. The paint will powderize as the surfaces spall, and that dust can still stain clothes, but at least it isn't sticky.

Comment: Agree here, best option is to disassemble what can be easily disassembled, clean with soap and water. Check for any rough or rusted, loose tracks, or gouged tracks and replace as needed, or sand/file to make smooth. On the track areas, I would use a door track lube, like used for garage doors, patio doors, etc. Graphite or a white lithium would be good for the crank area or any geared sections. As far as greasy/sticky attracting grease...I think Harper meant dust and dirt. When they attract dust and dirt, it turns the grease into sandpaper, this then rub and breaks down the surfaces.

Comment: If you feel ambitious, then you could take it all apart, clean and paint what areas need to be repainted, then do the lubrication needed. Oh, if some areas are plastic, or a wheel, then best bet is to replace the plastic or wheel rather than lubricate it.